# Maintain right to left Hebrew in English table

Tags: hebrew

Put simply, the Hebrew word comes out correctly in the first instance but backwards in the second. How can I maintain right to left orientation of the text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}

\begin{cjhebrew}
b*:re’+siyt 
\end{cjhebrew}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
English L to R text & \begin{cjhebrew}b*:re’+siyt\end{cjhebrew} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual, it looks like you should use `\cjRL` for inline Hebrew:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}

\begin{cjhebrew}
b*:re’+siyt 
\end{cjhebrew}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
English L to R text & \cjRL{b*:re’+siyt} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot for missing that. Many thanks!